# Merging overlapping intervals based on a max count for number of guests

Tags: c#, algorithm, merge, intervals, overlap

I want to make a program that counts how many guests are present at the same time. All guests have an arrival and exit time. I've counted the max numbers of guests already and it can give me one time when it's at its max. What I want is all the time intervals when the max number of guests is present

I've tried to do it with an overlapping method, but it doesn't quite work, probably because it's comparing too much or too little values from the lists. I have two lists, arrival and exit where I add values when it's written on my console application.

I tried adding the times coming from time and time2 in one list and sorting that, but it adds way too many values for some test inputs.

```
int max = 1; int count = 1; 
int i = 1; int j = 0; 
long time = arrival[0]; long time2= dep[0];

        while (i < n1 && j < n1) // n1 is the length of the input integer
        {
            if (arrival[i] < dep[j])
            {
                count++;

                if (count >= max)
                {
                    max = count;  
                    time = arrival[i];  
                    time2= dep[j];                 
                }   

        // possible location of console.writeline(time1 + time2)     
        // somewhere here I would add time and time2 to a new list

             i++;              
            }

            else
            {
                count--;
                j++;
            }
        } Console.WriteLine(max); Console.WriteLine(time1 + " " + time2);
```

So let's say my input is 5 guests with intervals: (12,30), (18,25), (25,40), (13,15) and (32,36) the wanted result would be

2 // max guests at the time

13 15 // new line for every interval

18 30

32 36

But I can't get it to work, it only shows 32-36. If I put console.writeline in the possible location it gives me: 13-15, 18-25, 25-30, 32-36. With other test inputs with more duplicates (like 0 to 5 appears more than once in the list) it gives me way too many intervals.

Comment: Please specify the range of time intervals and how many guests you have.

Comment: You have a type of problem that is referred to Telephone Trunk Line Problem which is to determine the number of Trunk Lines that a company requires based on the peak number of calls.  Computer Scientist at Bell Labs years ago worked on the solution.  The solution was to first create a table of 5 minute periods for the time period being used. Then process each call by adding 1 to the time period where a call starts and every 5 minute period until the called ended.  Then the peak number of calls is the highest number in the table.

Comment: n guests smaller than 1000000 and intervals ranging between 0 seconds and 3000000. Each interval has its own range but it can be the same as other guests. There is no set range, they can stay 1 second or 10 etc.

Comment: This would benefit from defining a function instead of writing console code. The inputs could be a list of arrival/departure pairs and a specific time. Looking at that function and seeing what it inputs and outputs would make it much easier to understand the problem. Even if the function is empty, it makes it easier to see what's going in and what you're expecting back.

Comment: @jdweng what does your comment refer too?

Comment: The way of solving the issue is to build a table that contain time periods (like 5 minute time periods) with two columns Time and Number of Guests.  Then fill the data with guest time at party.  In this case make a table with rows from 12 to 36 in one row steps.  Then guest 1 add one to rows 12 to 30.  Then Guest 2 add one to rows 18 to 25.  Then Guest 3 add one to rows 25 to 40.  Then Guest 4 add one to rows 13 to 15.  Finally Guest 4 add one to rows 32 to 36.  The row with the max value is the answer.

Comment: The resolution of the time period has to be smaller than the minimum time for each guest.  Creating time periods like this is called BINs.  A bin is a fixed size where you insert a range of data.  It is like selling Tomatoes.  The good ones you sell for  $5.00 a pound.  The average ones you sell for $3.00 a pound.  And the left overs you sell for $1.00 pound.  Each price is a different BIN.  You have three different bins.  In this problem you have bins which are 1 minute long and go from 12 to 36.  If a guest stays one second you still put the guest into a 1 minute bin.

Answer (score 1):

Make array or list of structures containing both arrival and departure times for all guests together with `+1/-1` flag denoting type of event (+1 for arrival).

Sort list by time field. In case of tie put arrival event first, if you want to register two guests in zero interval (one enters, another exits at the same time), or departure first otherwise - seems your case.

Make `Count = 0` and `MaxCount`.

Go through the list, adding flag field to `Count`.

Value of `Count` after every event denotes number of the quests in the room.

```
Guests  (12,30), (18,25), (25,40), (13,15) and (32,36)
Events     12;1   13;1   15;-1   18;1   25;-1   25;1  30;-1  32;1   36;-1   40;-1
Count  0      1      2       1      2       1      2      1     2       1       0  
                     ^       x      ^       x      ^      x     ^       x
Max intervals (^-x)
```

When `Count` reaches `MaxCount` - start new output interval, when it becomes `MaxCount - 1` - finish that interval and add it to `OutList`

When `Count` exceeds `MaxCount` - clear `OutList`, make `MaxCount - Count` and  start new output interval

In the end output `MaxCount` and intervals from `OutList`

Comment: I have to say I like this approach! How can we get the requested output (`2 13-15 18-30 32-36`)?

Comment: @miloszlakomy I added more description

Comment: Nice, I think the algorithm is complete now. 